# Compute discrete probability distribution using linear algebra

Tags: probability

Given a discrete joint probability distribution, $P(a,b)$, is it possible to obtain a conditional distribution $P(a|b)$ or $P(b|a)$, by operating on the  the table of probabilities, using the matrix operations of linear algebra?

More generally, if the cells of a matrix describe probabilities of the outcomes of various discrete states of two variables, is it possible to make use of operations, such as matrix multiplication, matrix inversion, determinants .etc to arrive at joint, marginal, and conditional distribution matrices?

Comment: Row and column sums should give you marginals.

Comment: Thanks, I think this would be equivalent to multiplying on the left or right by a vector of all 1's.

Comment: And for conditionals just normalize the row or column in question.